# CRTL + Backspace delete (kill) word

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

This seems to be a simple answer to find online but surprisingly I haven't been able to find a solution that works in my system.

I have a Macbook pro with ZSH / Oh-My-zsh installed with a couple of plugins. Basically what I want to try and configure is to have the same behavior of Crtl + W to work with Crtl + Backspace. If I put `bindkey '^?' backward-kill-word` in my .zshrc file then pressing only backspace deletes the entire word, which is almost what I want but with the Crtl + Backspace and not just the backspace.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with a little helper C program.

```
#include <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
int main() {
   return CGEventSourceFlagsState(1);
}
```

Compiled with `gcc modkeys.c -framework CoreGraphics`
The `a.out` needs to be moved to `/usr/bin/local/modkeys`

Now in your `.zshrc`

```
function my-backspace () {
  /usr/local/bin/modkeys
  local KEYS_MODIFIERS=$?
  # backspace + left control
  if [ $KEYS_MODIFIERS -eq 1 ]; then
    zle backward-kill-word
  else 
    zle backward-delete-char
  fi
}

zle -N my-backspace
bindkey '^?' my-backspace
```

The drawback of this solution is it will work locally only, any remote terminal ssh sessions won't have access to `/usr/bin/local/modkeys`.

Comment: Wow! thanks, no wonder I couldn't find an answer. Didn't think it was that complicated.